# What's the reason for specifying only the 'field' option for the Term & Phrase suggesters in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

When using the suggester API, we are forced to specify the **field** option :

```
"suggest" : {
  "text" : "val",
  "sug_name" : {      
    "term" : {
      "field" : "field_name"
    }
  }
}
```

Is this field supposed to be a valid field name of some type ?

If so, fields can exist only in the context of types AFAIK.
Why isn't possible to also specify (at least optionally) the type the field belongs to ?

Answer (score 0):

Is your question if "field" has to be a valid field? 
YES it does if you want it to find anything, you are welcome to search for fields that dont exist, although that seems an odd thing to do.

Your second question, the answer, I believe, is NO, you can not specify a `_type` using the `_suggest` api, you can use a `suggest` block with the [_search api as shown here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters.html)

```
curl -s -XPOST 'localhost:9200/_search' -d '{
  "query" : {
    ...
  },
  "suggest" : {
    ...
  }
}'
```

Comment: I can't think of a reason to specify the field without the type. One may want to specify both or neither, only the field seems very odd to me.

Comment: The query part is not important. It has no influence on the suggest results.